# Is possible to use a 220 V to 220 V isolation transformer for 110 V and get 110 V in the secondary?

Tags: voltage, transformer

I need to buy a 110 V to 110 V isolation transformer to isolate a device from mains, but I can only find 220 V to 110 V or 220 V to 220 V.

Can I use a 220 V to 220 V transformer for 110 V to 110 V? What happens with the power rating?

Comment: How much power does the device use?

Comment: You should keep frequency in mind as well as voltage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Can I use a 220V to 220V transformer in 110V to 110V? What happens
> with the power rating?*

Yes you can use it but the power rating will reduce proportionately. This is because the full-load current handling of the transformer cannot increase at a lower voltage i.e. it is what it is and you are stuck with that maximum current.

<sub>There are two basic things that govern the VA rating of a transformer. The first thing is limiting the supply voltage to avoid excessive magnetic core saturation. The 2nd thing is limiting the current handling capacity of the wires to prevent excessive \$I^2R\$ heat. Clearly, lowering the voltage isn't going to make things worse regards core saturation but, you still cannot exceed the maximum current handling of the transformer winding wires.</sub>

Comment: I see, so if I have a 220v:220v 50VA, in 110V, I can use half of it?

Comment: You can rely on it handling 25 VA @0x3333

Comment: Makes total sense, perfect! Thanks

Comment: Quarter power, actually: at most half to meet the same current rating, but the voltage drop under load ("regulation") remains the same, so if you need the same regulation, halve it again.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers:

You can use two 110V to 220V transformers back to back. Yes, you will incur extra loss, but transformers are fairly efficient, so two back to back will take you from something like mid 90's to mid 80's efficiencywise.

I've done this a couple of times when I need isolation. Microwave oven transformers can handle well over a kilowatt, and can be picked up for 50$ in a retailer near you... And for that price they even include a microwave oven with the transformer.

Comment: You can also use two identical transformers with secondaries connected together. So, for instance, 120->24->24-120.

Comment: Make that $25-35. Or $1 at Goodwill.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at video arcade parts sites, you can find a 110V to 110V isolation transformers. I would post a link but not sure if that's allowed.

As it is allowed, no affiliation:

https://www.arcadepartsandrepair.com/store/cabinet-parts/power-supplies/monitor-isolation-transformer-120v-output/

Comment: Links are allowed and welcome as long as you disclose any affiliation with what you're linking to. Links to general shops and similar is fine :)

Comment: Downvote nullified.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though, if allowed, it's a way to get around the "don't ask shopping questions".

Answer (score -2):

Mouser has about 15 different transformers rated 50-100 VA with suitable primaries and secondaries. [Here](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Triad-Magnetics/N-68X?qs=%252BfhPKvh1fqMgz%2FL8G7F80A%3D%3D) is one for less than $20.

[image: Layer wound transformer]

If you need better isolation (split bobbin), [Here](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bel-Signal-Transformer/DP-241-7-120?qs=0%2F2GmT7MRM%252BkISYrShut1w%3D%3D) is a 56 VA unit for about $26.

[image: Split bobbin transformer]

Comment: Please explain the downvote. I realize that the OP wanted to know if a 220/220 transformer can be used on 110 VAC, but the reason was being unable to find the proper part.

Comment: OPs question is an interesting EE-question, one which you don't answer. "Where do I buy X" is not, and such questions are not on-topic.